# Is there a way to select multiple values by default

Tags: shiny

Is there a way to select multiple values by default in selectinput.
Here I need first 2 values to be shown in selectinput by default.

I tried doing it as shown below but not able to achieve

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

nba <- data.frame(
  player = c("James", "Durant", "Curry", "Harden", "Paul", "Wade"), 
  team = c("CLEOH", "GSWOAK", "GSWOAK", "HOUTX", "HOUTX", "CLEOH"),
  day1points = c("25","23","30","41","26","20"), 
  day2points = c("24","25","33","45","26","23"),
  rating=c("1","2","3","4","5","1")
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="SADDAS",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("var1_select")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("reportOutput"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$var1_select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "ind_var_select",
      "Select Names", 
      choices = as.character(nba[,1] ),
      multiple = TRUE,
      selected = as.character(c(nba[1,1],nba[1,2]))
    )
  })
  
  output$reportOutput = renderTable({
    # Filter it
    subset(nba[,1:3], player %in% input$ind_var_select)
  }, options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `selected = as.character(c(nba[1,1],nba[2,1]))`

Comment: Thanks. I missed it :(

Comment: @YBS . Is there a way to achieve similar solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184620/is-there-a-way-to-split-the-characters-in-selectinput